# Find the average of certain fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has 3 columns (name, course, grade). My 'name' column contains three students, 'course' column contains different courses like math, physics, etc. 
What I need is to find the average of physics and math for each student.
I have no idea how I should use AVG() function. I know how to find the average of all grades for each student, but I need some help here.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: you only want to find the average for those two course only?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanna do.

Comment: One student has multiple rows for same course in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT name, AVG(grade) FROM table1 where course IN ('math','physics')
>   GROUP BY name

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
SELECT name as Student, AVG(grade) as Average 
FROM grade_table 
WHERE course IN ('math','physics') 
GROUP BY name
```

The result will then be like:

```
| Student | Average  |
|   Sam   |  5.0000  |
|  Johan  |  4.5000  |
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you average grades for math and physics course for each student, use below

```
SELECT course,AVG(grade) FROM table1 WHERE course IN('math','physics')
GROUP BY course
```

If you want average grades for each course for each student,use below

```
SELECT course,AVG(grade) FROM table1 GROUP BY course
```